# Dragable <div>. Fight with selection

Tags: html, dom, draggable, textselection

I develop my own simple js lib to drag `<div>`

When I drag it then I often select text under `<div>`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Sw7Ty/

Obviously it is something (text selection) I do not wish to happen.

It happens in Google Chrome.

(In FireFox I have another issue that I will ask in other thread)

**WORKING CODE**

working code: http://jsfiddle.net/6Kwd4/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi make some quick tests on your jsfiddle :

so i think its about `e.preventDefault()`; in the mouseXXX events.